# Passing environment variables to application in a Docker container through docker-compose

Tags: docker, environment-variables, docker-compose, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.0

I want to pass environment variables to the applications containerized in Docker through docker-compose. This is a VS 2017 15.3 solution Tools for Docker.

In my **docker.compose.yml** file I have:

```
  app.web:
    image: app.web
    env_file: 
      - ./path.to.project/config.env
    build:
      context: ./path.to.project
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

In **config.env** I have:

```
TEST=Compose
```

But when I try to read the variables using `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEST");` I always get null.

If I set a non-existent file in `env_file` it complains when I run it, so I give for granted that is locating the file.

If I set the variable this way:

```
  app.web:
    image: app.web
    environment: 
      - TEST=ComposeLiteral
    build:
      context: ./path.to.project
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

I get "ComposeLiteral" when evaluating "TEST".

Which is the correct way of passing a file with environment variables to the application?

Comment: Are you trying to get this variable during the build of your image or during the execution?

Comment: During the execution. The idea is to allow the containerized application to read those values.

Comment: Linux. It uses .NET Core 2.0

Comment: try with `env_file: ./path.to.project/config.env`.

Comment: It does not work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the config.env file I was using was starting with the [UTF8 BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), making text editors to show me the same content, but causing docker compose to read something else.

When you add a text file through Visual Studio, the BOM is added.

I created an [example project with the problem](https://github.com/vtortola/dotnet-docker-env).

[image]

Then in the log is possible to see how the wrong parsing is happening:

config.env:

```
environment:
  NUGET_FALLBACK_PACKAGES: /root/.nuget/fallbackpackages
  "\uFEFFTEST": Compose
```

config2.env

```
environment:
  NUGET_FALLBACK_PACKAGES: /root/.nuget/fallbackpackages
  TEST: Compose
```

https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/5220

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to reproduce your problem.  If I start with your Dockerfile:

```
version: "2"

services:
  app.web:
    image: app.web
    env_file: 
      - ./path.to.project/config.env
    build:
      context: ./path.to.project
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

And in `path.to.project` I use the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine
RUN apk add --update python3
COPY dumpenv.py /dumpenv.py
CMD python3 /dumpenv.py
```

Which runs a simple web server that does nothing but dump environment variables:

```
import http.server
import os


class Handler(http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/plain')
        self.end_headers()

        content = []

        for k, v in os.environ.items():
            content.append('{:20} {}'.format(k, v))

        self.wfile.write(bytes('\n'.join(content), 'utf-8'))
        return


server = http.server.HTTPServer(('0.0.0.0', 8080), Handler)
server.serve_forever()
```

If I `docker-compose up` this environment and then connect to the service, I see:

```
PWD                  /
TEST                 ComposeLiteral
HOSTNAME             5388e6e2717a
SHLVL                1
HOME                 /root
PATH                 ...
```

You can find this complete example online [here](https://github.com/larsks/so-example-46431025).  If you see different behavior using this same example, could you update your question to include a complete reproducer?

Comment: Isn't there a way that does not involve running ad-hoc scripts? It seems by the documentation it should be possible.

Comment: I don't follow you.  There are no ad-hoc scripts here.  There is just an environment variable successfully being passed through to the Docker `CMD`.

Comment: My apologies, you are right. I fast-readed your post in my mobile and miss-understood it. Your code runs fine, and is exactly what I was trying to do myself. However, the problem is that my config.env starts with the UTF8 BOM. Many thanks for taking the time of making an example.